# How to extract surface triangles from a tetrahedral mesh?

Tags: c++, unity-game-engine, 3d, rendering, game-physics

I want to render a tetrahedral mesh using some 3D software. However, I cannot directly load the tetrahedral mesh in the software of my choice (e.g. Blender) as the file format that I have for tetrahedral meshes is not supported. So I should somehow extract the faces with corresponding vertex indices myself.

For a cube, my tetrahedral file contains vertex IDs for each tetrahedron which includes 4 faces is as follow:

```
v 0.41 0.41 0.41
v 0.41 0.41 -0.41
v 0.41 -0.41 0.41
v 0.41 -0.41 -0.41
v -0.41 0.41 0.41
v -0.41 0.41 -0.41
v -0.41 -0.41 0.41
v -0.41 -0.41 -0.41
t 0 1 2 4
t 5 1 4 7
t 1 2 4 7
t 3 1 7 2
t 6 4 2 7
```

However, I'm not sure how I can and extract the surface mesh given this data. Does someone know how I can do this or what the algorithm is?

Comment: each v line is the x y z coordinates of some vertex.  Each t line is the first, second, third, optionally fourth index of the vertices of a triangle or quad. [Here](https://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/procedural-grid/) is a good tutorial for creating a mesh in unity when you know vertex positions and how the vertices are connected into triangles.

Comment: @Ruzihm I know what each `v` line mean but I'm not sure how to get 4 faces out of each `t` line

Comment: why dont you share the code or application that produced the file?

Comment: @Ruzihm I don't have access to that. I just have these tetrahedral mesh files

Comment: What I don't understand is why you say this has 4 faces but I see 5 .. also why is each of these faces apparently build up of 4 instead of 3 vertices? ... If it were a tetrahedron shouldn't it only have 4 vertices and 4 faces?

Comment: I think I figured how to get the faces from the `t` lines. It's basically juts getting 4 choose 3 vertex sets. The surface mesh is represented by faces that do not share a common vertex in a tetrahedron. I'll post an answer later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is a simplistic brute force method. For each tetrahedron, for example look at the third one, `t: 1 2 4 7`, by removing each vertex, generate all four combination of three vertices out of the four tetrahedral vertices, i.e.

```
face[t][0]: 1 2 4,  face[t][1]: 1 2 7,  face[t][2]: 1 4 7, face[t][3]: 2 4 7
```

and sort each triangle's integer labels in ascending order (for uniqueness)
This way, you can generate the list (or some kind of array) of all faces of all tetrahedral from the tetrahedral mesh.

Now run a loop over the list of all triangle faces that you have just generated, looking for duplicates. Whenever a triangle is contained twice in the list of all triangle faces, you remove it, because it is an interior triangle, i.e. two adjacent tetrahedral share this triangular face, so it is interior face and not a boundary one.

Whatever is left after this procedure, are only the boundary (i.e. the surface) triangle faces of the tetrahedral mesh.

Here is an example of this algorithm written in python

```py
import numpy as np

def list_faces(t):
  t.sort(axis=1)
  n_t, m_t= t.shape 
  f = np.empty((4*n_t, 3) , dtype=int)
  i = 0
  for j in range(4):
    f[i:i+n_t,0:j] = t[:,0:j]
    f[i:i+n_t,j:3] = t[:,j+1:4]
    i=i+n_t
  return f

def extract_unique_triangles(t):
  _, indxs, count  = np.unique(t, axis=0, return_index=True, return_counts=True)
  return t[indxs[count==1]]

def extract_surface(t):
  f=list_faces(t)
  f=extract_unique_triangles(f)
  return f

V = np.array([
[ 0.41,  0.41,  0.41],
[ 0.41,  0.41, -0.41],
[ 0.41, -0.41,  0.41],
[ 0.41, -0.41, -0.41],
[-0.41,  0.41,  0.41],
[-0.41,  0.41, -0.41],
[-0.41, -0.41,  0.41],
[-0.41, -0.41, -0.41]])

T = np.array([
              [0, 1, 2, 4],
              [5, 1, 4, 7],
              [1, 2, 4, 7],
              [3, 1, 7, 2],
              [6, 4, 2, 7]])


F_all = list_faces(T)
print(F_all)
print(F_all.shape)

F_surf = extract_surface(T)
print(F_surf)
print(F_surf.shape)
```

Answer (score 1):

A very efficient method is using hashsets  (aka `set` in python, `std::unordered_set` in c++, `HashSet` in rust)

The principle of retreiving an envelope from a volume of tetraedrons is the same as retreiving the outline of a surface of triangles ([as you can find here](https://github.com/jimy-byerley/pymadcad/blob/80dadac843354acf0d5998103181053bbcf17169/madcad/mesh.py#L424))

This gives in python the following code, easy to translate in any language with hashsets (in python here, for simplicity):

```py
envelope = set()
for tet in tetraedrons:
    for face in (  (tet[0], tet[1], tet[2]), 
                   (tet[0], tet[2], tet[3]), 
                   (tet[0], tet[3], tet[2]),
                   (tet[1], tet[3], tet[2]) ):
        # if face has already been encountered, then it's not on the envelope
        # the magic of hashsets makes that check O(1) (eg. extremely fast)
        if face in envelope:    envelope.remove(face)
        # if not encoutered yet, add it flipped
        else:                   envelope.add((face[2], face[1], face[0]))

# there is now only faces encountered once (or an odd number of times for paradoxical meshes)
return envelope
```